# Regarding running multiple ssh commands using perl

Tags: perl, ssh

I am bit stuck here I want to ssh in to a machine and then run about 3 commands which are basically setup commands and then i want to return back to my machine with env variables of that machine

like

```
setup1
setup2
setup3
env > envtext.txt.
return back
```

All this i have to do in perl

i tried commands like
`system("ssh @machine command1 && command 2")` doesnt work

is there something like?

```
system("ssh @machine command1 -cmd command 2 -cmd command 3")
```

if not than what is the best way to do it 
like making a shell script then calling it or i can do it in perl itself without any shell scripts?

code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Net::SSH::Perl;


my $host = "address";
my $user = "name";
my $password = "password";
```

## -- set up a new connection

```
 my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host,
    debug=>0,

    identity_files => ['path to key'],
           options=> ["StrictHostKeyChecking  no"]
           #interactive => yes,
    );
```

## -- authenticate

```
$ssh->login($user,$password);
```

## -- execute the command

```
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("env");

print $stdout;`
```

error it gives is Permission denied at ssh.pl line 25

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is about SSHing to a *single* remote host and running *multiple* commands there. If that's true, then you need to pack your multiple commands up into a single command line that the remote shell can execute. The easiest way to do this is to use the list form of `system`, and pass the command line as a single parameter:

```
system "ssh", "machine", "setup1; setup2; setup3";
```

On to the second part of your question: You want to get data back from the remote side. For that, you'll want your program to read SSH's output rather than using `system`. For this, you can use:

```
open my $FH, "-|", "ssh", "machine", "setup1; setup2; setup3; env";
my @lines_from_ssh = <$FH>;
close $FH;
```

If you also need to send input to the remote side, look into IPC::Open2. If you need to capture both stdout and stderr, see IPC::Open3.

Comment: I am able to send the commands but my problem now is that i am getting the same env variable files that setup1 gives one file setup 2 gives another env variable file both are same but both should be different.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment, but it sounds like a different issue. Since you are not able to send multiple commands to your remote server, would you mind accepting this answer and asking a new question for your next issue?

Comment: what i meant is that the env variable file that i get is of the one after setup1 not after setup2 i have kept env > envtest.txt after setup2 but still i get the file having env variables of the first file

Comment: You'd have to explain what `setup1` and `setup2` are doing. Also, keep in mind that processes can't affect the environment of their parent process, only that of their children.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do :

```
system("ssh $_ command1 -cmd command 2 -cmd command 3") for @machines;
```

Another Pure Perl solution is to use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH)

Comment: I tried using NET::SSH::PERL it says permission denied i gave the location of the key still it says denied but the interactive mode is working but batchmode is not. Any ideas why

Comment: I could not use the command you said its not working i tried  Net::OpenSSH it said could not find package. any other ideas you have?

Comment: Are you using ssh key pairs + `ssh-agent` ? If not, you should.

Comment: no I am not can you guide me to any document where i can understand more about it?

Comment: @sputnik   I did all those things and then only i am trying to connect. Now i am writing a shell script where i am able to do ssh but the problem is that i want env variables after doing setup2 but i always get the env variables of setup 1 shell scripts consists of setup1 then sleep 20 then setup 2 sleep 40 and env > test.txt thats it any ideas why???